# Failed to select specific worker over consumer tag

Tags: rabbitmq

I have defined worker like this:

```
...    
$this->objChannel->basic_consume(
        'QueueDeclare',
        'orange', 
        false,                 
        false,
        false,
        false,
        [$this, 'ProcessClientRequest']
    );
    ...
```

I have set "orange" as consumer tag.

There are other workers with same declare "QueueDeclare".+ but different consumer tag.

Now I'm trying to send job to that specific worker with "orange" consumer tag.

```
...
$objMessage = new AMQPMessage(
    json_encode($arrWork),
    [
        'delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT,
        'consumer_tag'  => 'organge',
    ]
);
...
```

Problem is when I send couple of times RabbitMQ sends job to all workers, not just to that one with organe consumer tag.

What is my situation?
I have couple of workers running which are creating large files.
Process is in the way that I send for example 500 rows as one task, and till I'm done with job.

Because of that process, it is important to me when I start with job that only one worker receives that specific file.

If worker with orange consumer tag start with file_123, it has to do whole process, it has to receive all rows.

Is really consumer tag made for that or there is something else?

I have shown above only code which is important for this explanation.

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE 1:**

I can see on queue list that every worker/connection has consumer_tag and also in clients message.

**UPDATE 2:**

Or maybe I can select specific channel when there are couple of them with same queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution (I'm sure there are other solutions but this one worked for me).

For every worker define two "QueueDeclare", one which will be same for all workers and one random, for example uniqid().

On first send message to common "QueueDeclare" and resolve if that was init message, if it was save somewhere random name so client can grab it and send real work on it.
After that client can send unlimited messages to that same worker.